# What is the "threefold sanctification" that is referred to in Tachanun?

Tags: tefilla

The Tachanun prayer includes the language, "those who proclaim three-fold sanctifications to the Holy One". What are the "three-fold sanctifications"? Are they the "al hamicha" blessings recited after partaking of grain products (other than bread or matzah) made from wheat, barley, rye, oats or spelt; wine or grape juice; and/or grapes, figs, pomegranates, olives or dates? If they are, indeed, those blessings, why were those blessings made reference to and not Birkat HaMazon which one would presume has a "higher" level of "sanctification"? Many thanks for any assistance and Pesach Kasher v'Sameach.

Answer (score 3):

From the original Hebrew the answer seems self evident.

שׁוֹמֵר גּוֹי קָדוֹשׁ שְׁמוֹר שְׁאֵרִית עַם קָדוֹשׁ וְאַל יֹאבַד גּוֹי קָדוֹשׁ הַמְשַׁלְּ֒שִׁים בְּשָׁלשׁ קְדֻשּׁוֹת לְקָדוֹשׁ:‏

We say in the Kedusha prayers קדוש קדוש קדוש, from Isaiah 6:3. I assume that's what it's referring to.

Comment: Even more evident from the Yekke minhog: בשלש קדשות קדוש קדוש קדוש